# Why 'nobody', instead of 'anybody' or 'anyone', is used in this context?

Tags: word-usage

> "The Sorcerer's Stone! Of course -- the Elixir of Life! But I don't understand who --"
>
> "Can you think of ***nobody*** who has waited many years to return to power, who has clung to life, awaiting their chance?" ... ...

I think '*nobody*' here refers to *Voldermort*. I don't understand why '*nobody*' is being used in this context. I figure it might mean the sense: *a person of no influence, authority, or importance*. But I think **Voldermort** isn't that kind of person. On the contrary, he meant a lot to all the people in the book. Otherwise, '*anyone*' or '*anybody*' looks more appropriate for this context in my opinion.

Any thoughts?

-- Excerpted from Harry Potter.

Comment: "Can you think of nobody..." has the same meaning of "Can't you think of anybody..."  The negative word is just moved to a different place. I think the "Can...nobody" construction is more common in BrE than AmE.

Comment: @CanadianYankee That make much sense!

Comment: Or "can you *not* think of anybody". Stated with emphasis, possibly rude or impolite in this form, unless spoken by an elder or teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a way of saying that the other person is being a little obtuse.

> I wonder why he's kneeling  on one knee at the restaurant table and looking earnestly into that woman's eyes.
>   -- Can you think of **no reason** why he might be doing that?